# Identifier 'EXTRACTVALUE' must be declaredCompilation failed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I tryed to retrive xml data to variable but giving me error saying "identifier 'EXTRACTVALUE' must be declaredCompilation failed"

```
VarConverstionFact    NUMBER;  
 BEGIN

    VarConverstionFact := TO_NUMBER(ExtractValue(PXML, '/OBJECT/Item/ItemUomLevelsList/ItemUomLevels/ConversionFactor'));

    IF VarConverstionFact > 0 THEN

      SELECT BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SQ_ITEM_ID.NEXTVAL INTO varID FROM DUAL;
      END IF;
END;
```

This is save xml nodes

```
 <Item>
<LocationId>0</LocationId>
<Id>0</Id>
 <ItemId>0</ItemId>
<ItemCode>SC12</ItemCode>
<ItemDescription>SCDITEM</ItemDescription>

<ItemUomLevelsList>
  <ItemUomLevels>
    <UomLevelId>1</UomLevelId>
    <UomId>9</UomId>
    <UomLongName>LG</UomLongName>
    <ConversionFactor>-53</ConversionFactor>
    <UomLevelStatus>1</UomLevelStatus>
    <UomLevelSystemUsageTypeId>2</UomLevelSystemUsageTypeId>
    <UomLevelImage>0</UomLevelImage>
    <UomLevelControlsList>
      <UomLevelControls>
        <ControlId>2</ControlId>
      </UomLevelControls>
    </UomLevelControlsList>
    <UomDimensionsList>
      <UomDimensions>
        <DimensionId>14</DimensionId>
        <DimensionValue>12</DimensionValue>
      </UomDimensions>
      <UomDimensions>
        <DimensionId>12</DimensionId>
        <DimensionValue>13</DimensionValue>
      </UomDimensions>
    </UomDimensionsList>
  </ItemUomLevels>
</ItemUomLevelsList>
```

When i Try to insert i'm getting no data error in when i put VarConverstionFact =0 if i VarConverstionFact = -53 i'm getting  invalid number error.

```
select to_number(ExtractValue(PXML, '/OBJECT/Item/ItemUomLevelsList/ItemUomLevels/ConversionFactor'))
```

INTO VarConverstionFact FROM DUAL;

I used this after i got this as a answer my package was complied without errors but when i try to insert above xml i got error which is mention earlier (above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtractValue isn't a PLSQL function, and can only be used as part of an SQL statement I think.

You could either do:

```
select to_number(ExtractValue(PXML, '/OBJECT/Item/ItemUomLevelsList/ItemUomLevels/ConversionFactor')) 
INTO VarConverstionFact FROM DUAL;
```

or

```
VarConverstionFact := PXML.extract('/OBJECT/Item/ItemUomLevelsList/ItemUomLevels/ConversionFactor').getNumberVal();
```

EDIT: I'm assuming PXML is an XMLTYPE

Comment: {"ORA-01722: invalid number\nORA-06512: at \"SYS.XMLTYPE\", line 181\nORA-06512: at \"BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM\", line 165\nORA-06512: at line 1"}

I'm getting this error when im using that code

Comment: Is the value you're trying to extract definitely a number? That exception suggests the value you're trying to store as a number is not actually a number. Spaces or other characters may be causing issues.

Comment: Could you paste the xml node you're trying to extract? That error pretty much only comes up when you're trying to convert something that isn't a number to a number. It may be worth trying to put the value into a varchar2 variable so you can see what is coming back. edit: which approach from the two above did you use by the way?

Comment: Yes i did use but when i'm try to insert data im getting that above error 

I did edit my question with xml nodes

Comment: You're trying to extract the "ConversionFactor" node using the xpath you provided ('/OBJECT/Item/ItemUomLevelsList/ItemUomLevels/ConversionFactor'). In your xml the ConversionFactor node is "CD", which is not a valid number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79945/discussion-between-chrisrs2292-and-beez).